# JavaScript Image flickering upon onmouseover and onmouseout

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to do a mouseover to popup a larger image of the default image. However, whenever I hover over the smaller image, it does popup but when I hover over the popup image, it keeps on flickering.

Below is my code:

HTML:

```
<div class="thumbnail" id="thumbnail1">
    <img src="image1.jpg" onmouseover="enlarge1()" onmouseout="minimize1()"/>            
</div>
```

JS:

```
function enlarge1() {
    var parent = document.getElementById("thumbnail1");
    var child = document.createElement("IMG");
    child.setAttribute("src", "image-large1.jpg");
    child.setAttribute("width", "350%");
    child.setAttribute("alt", "Related Large 1");
    child.style.position="absolute";
    child.style.zIndex="1";
    child.style.bottom="15%";
    child.style.left="30%";

    parent.appendChild(child);

}

function minimize1() {
    var parent = document.getElementById("thumbnail1");
    var child = parent.lastElementChild;
    parent.removeChild(child);
}
```

Comment: It's flickering because when you mouseover the large image - the small image is no longer being moused over - so the large image closes - but now that's it's closed - the small image is being moused over again - so it reopens, etc.

Comment: Skip all that and use CSS.  http://jsfiddle.net/jhwo3k5p/  You can also use `transform: scale(3.5)`.

Comment: @Brad, arguably, the same problem could occur if instead of scaling up on hover we do scale down: http://jsfiddle.net/jhwo3k5p/1/

Comment: @Kaiido Arguably, you'll sink a boat if you drill a hole through the bottom of it, but that's not what the question asks, now is it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to...

1. Move the mouse events onto the wrapping div
2. change them to `onmouseenter` and `onmouseleave`

```
<div class="thumbnail" id="thumbnail1" onmouseenter="enlarge1()" onmouseleave="minimize1()">
    <img src="image1.jpg" alt=''>
</div>
```

---

That way, when you are hovering over *either* image, it's still in "hover" mode — and, unlike `onmouseover`, `onmousenter` only triggers once (when you enter the div) so it won't retrigger when you switch from hovering over the small to the large image.

Answer (score 0):

You can use mouseenter and mouseleave， not mouseover and mouseout.

Because the mouseover event will be invoked once you move mouse over the DOM or it's child DOM. So it may be invoked many times when you move mouse over the larger image.

But, for mouseenter, only when you enter the DOM, it will be invoked, not for it's child. It will not be invoked when you move mouse over the larger image.

```js
var x = 0;
var z = 0;
function myEnterFunction() {
    document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = x+=1;
}
function myMoveFunction() {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = z+=1;
}
```

```css
div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: 10px;
    float: left;
    padding: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: lightgray;
}

p {
    background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div onmouseenter="myEnterFunction()">
<img style="width: 100px;height: 100px;background-color:red;" src="" title="move mouse enter here"  />
<p>onmouseenter: <br> <span id="demo2">Mouse over me!</span></p>
</div>
<div onmousemove="myMoveFunction()">
  <p>onmousemove: <br> <span id="demo">Mouse over me!</span></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Changed from onmouseover to onmouseenter, the flickering still happen.

Comment: Try my example, whem mouse enter into the inner img,  the mouseenter handle will not be invoked , but mouseover handler will be invoked once you move over the outer div or the inner DOM.

Comment: And you can bind the mouseenter event to the wrapper div.

Answer (score 0):

Since writing this I have found it was only part successful.

As suggested, I used mouseenter and exit on the figure instead of the image.
On mouseenter I increase the dimensions of the figure for emphasis.
Putting the mouse pointer exactly between figures gave constant flickering so I tried
increasing the margin on the figures and it stopped the flicker.
Trial and error gave me a working fix without excessive gaps between figures.
Looks like mouseenter may not fire until you reach one of the elements inside the figure
Perhaps something using focus would give a more elegant solution.
Hope this helps someone